# Build failure when importing React Components with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm working on a project to integrate React and Golang together. I've made a first try and everything works as expected. But now I'm using webpack with babel-loader to generate my `bundle.js` and the program crash and i can't figoure out why.

When i type `webpack` in CLI, he send me this error:

```
Hash: 80aee336cd31d922b888
Version: webpack 4.16.4
Time: 261ms
Built at: 2018-08-03 16:05:28
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = ./bundle.js
[0] ./index.js 647 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:16)

   7 | }
   8 | 
>  9 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
     |                 ^
  10 |
```

That's my `index.js` who cause failure

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "rtsupport",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Realtime support frontend",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "G Descamps <gauthier1.descamps@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "serve": "^9.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

And my `webpack.config.js`:
    const webpack = require("webpack");
    const path = require("path");

```
let config= {
  entry:'./index.js',
  output: {
    path:__dirname,
    filename:'./bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules:[{
      test:/\.js$/,
      exclude:/node_modules/,
      loader:'babel-loader' 
    }]
  }
}

module.exports= config;
```

Here's my Github Repo if you need to see other file https://github.com/LaLauque/RealTimePlatform/tree/dev/rtsupport

Thanks a lot

Comment: filename: bundle.js

Comment: can you post directory structure?

Comment: You have to use the [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react.html) so that Babel recognizes the JSX.

Comment: create .babelrc file and add {"presets": ["env", "react"]}

Answer (score 0):

your App component does not has any `render() { ... }` function at here : https://github.com/LaLauque/RealTimePlatform/blob/dev/rtsupport/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

just render something and then check if it bundles add `render` function inside your App component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        Hello
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

also this `App` component will override the App component you importing from

```
import App from './components/App.jsx';
```

make sure to have specific names for each components....

Comment: also, no .babelrc